# access validation - Python

Tags: python, validation, for-loop, imap

I have a DF that has the following information:

```
    id email org        senha server         email_comp
    1  jj    @gmail.com 123   imap.gmail.com jj@gmail.com

    2  bb    @gmail.com 325   imap.gmail.com bb@gmail.com
```

I need to read those records one by one to do the validation in the email, but I can not think of a way to do this loop for all information. At the moment I achieved the following:

```
for nextServer in enumerate (imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(df['server'])):
```

But it continues giving error, if it were to do with HardCode the process would be as follows:

```
    while go:
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
mail.login(email_comp, senha)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my problem.

```
for idConfig, config in df.iterrows():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(df['smtp_server'])
    mail.login(df['from_email'],df['from_pwd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `apply()` method is a good fit here. It basically applies a function to every row (or column, if you pass `0` for the `axis` parameter) of the dataframe. If you write a function that does your desired actions (verification and login), you can then use `apply()` to call that function on each row the dataframe.

Something like this:

```
def verify(user):
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(user.server)
    mail.login(user.email_comp, user.senha)

df.apply(verify, axis = 1)
```